# Filter preload on many_to_many relationship

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have two models: `UserGroup` and `User`, with a `many_to_many` relationship.

In my UserGroup index action I do something like this:

```
user_groups =
  UserGroup
  |> Repo.all
  |> Repo.preload(:users)
```

And, in the view, when rendering user groups, I do something like this:

```
def render("index.json", %{user_groups: user_groups}) do
  %{
    user_groups:
      Enum.map(user_groups, fn user_group ->
        %{
          id: user_group.id,
          name: user_group.name,
          users: user_group.users
        }
      end)
  }
end
```

Change! Now users have a status, and I want to show just `active` users.

How can I "scope" the preload of users so only those with `active` status are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a partial query to `Repo.preload` with the `where` clause you want. Assuming the "active" users have `user.status == "active"`, you can do:

```
user_groups =
  UserGroup
  |> Repo.all
  |> Repo.preload(users: from(u in User, where: u.status == "active"))
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3).